# Splitting a folder into multiple folders without creating subfolders in terminal/ bash

Tags: linux, bash, split

How do I split a parent folder into 2 or more without creating subfolders.

like folder A into folderA1, FolderA2 but all in the same directory rather than being subfolders in folder A.

Actually this is the script I use but it only ends up creating subfolders

```
let fileCount=3000
let dirNum=1

for f in *
do
    [ -d $f ] && continue
    [ $fileCount -eq 3000 ] && {
        dir=$(printf "%03d" $dirNum)
        mkdir $dir
        let dirNum=$dirNum+1
        let fileCount=0
    }

    mv $f $dir
    let fileCount=$fileCount+1
done
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: @Cyrus: You are right, OP's update made the question much clearer

Comment: "Without creating subfolders" in the title is odd, do you mean without creating nested directories, or temporary directories, or something else? Clearly you want subdirectories to be created in the current directory.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve].  Your question is unclear (you want subdirectories but you do not want subdirectories !?!).  Then in the comments of the answer below, you specify how you want to split the files, which was not indicated in your question.  A good question is as important as a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

In the parent directory of `folderA`, run the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
i=0  # counter for current file
j=0  # counter for current directory
batchsize=1000 # size of each batch
find folderA -type f -print0 | while read -r -d $'\0' file 
do
    if (( i % batchsize == 0 )) 
    then
        (( j++ ))
        mkdir "dir_$j"
    fi
    mv -- "$file" "dir_$j"
    (( i++ ))
done
```

If all files in `folderA` have "normal" names, i.e. no whitespace, no glob characters, etc, the script can be written as

```
#!/bin/bash
find folderA -maxdepth 2 -type f | xargs -n 1000 | while read files 
do
     mkdir dir_$((++i))
     mv $files dir_$i/
done
```

Which is briefer, and also much more performant.

Comment: Folder A contains hundreds of thousands of files

Comment: @pRieS: So based on which criterion are you going to divide them?

Comment: I want each folder to contain just 1000 files, so when folderA1 gets 1000 files, mkdir FolderA2 and move 1000 files into that too ......

Comment: @pRieS: Ok, I make an update on the answer based on the requirement

Comment: Absolutely what i wanted. I'm sorry I wasn't able to express myself clearly but you got what I was trying to explain anyways. Thanks.